# Roots of a polynomial that is composed n times with itself

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, function-and-relation-composition

> Let $f(x)=x(4x^2-3)(64x^6-96x^4+36x^2-3)$ and $f^{(n)}=f(f(f(\cdots f(x))\cdots)$ (composed with itself $n$ times).
>   Prove that for all positive integers $n$, $f^{(n)}(x)=x$ has $9^n$ distinct real solutions $x$.

I could only manage to prove this for $n=1$. For that i put $2x=t$ and found the roots of $t(t^2-3)(t^6-6t^4+9t^2-3)=t$

$O$ is an obvious root. So, i proceeded to show that $(m-3)(m^3-6m^2+9m-3)=1$ has $4$ distinct positive roots.

Expanding i got $m^4-9m^3+27m^2-30m+8=0$. $2, 4$ are natural to guess and easy to verify and the other two roots by dividing out $(m-2)$ and $(m-4)$.

Now, someone please help  me to prove for $n>1$.

Comment: Use induction and count preimages.

Comment: Chebyshev polynomials have a composition property...

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x(4x^2-3)(64x^6-96x^4+36x^2-3)=256x^9-576x^7+432x^5-120x^3+9x=T_9(x)$$
Where $T_n(x)$ is the n-th Čebyšëv polynomials of the first kind.
It's known this nesting propriety:
$$T_n(T_m(x))=T_{nm}(x)$$
In addition, $T_n(x)$ has exatcly n reals roots.

So, using induction, soppose that the following holds:
$$f^{n}(x)=T_{9^n}(x)$$
So It has $9^n$ reals roots, 
Then
$$f^{n+1}(x)=f^n(f(x))=T_{9^n}(T_9(x))=T_{9^{n+1}}(x)$$
So It has $9^{n+1}$ roots.

In your question you said that you have proved that f^{(2)} holds. So by induction and by the proprieties of Čebyšëv polynomials $f^{(n)}(x)$ has exatcly $9^n$ reals roots $\forall n$